# C# sending e-mail with html link to file - unrecognized escape sequence

Tags: c#, html

I have a C# app that is sending an e-mail. I wish to send a link in the mail for users to click and open a file.

However where I have the link to my workbook I have issues. I have 5 errors all the same 'unrecognized escape sequence' where every "/" is. How do I get round this?

```
string htmlHeader = "<table style='font-size: 12pt;'>" +
            "<tr><a href='file:///G:\Shared\Team\New\Corporate%20Actions\Corp%20Events.xlsx'>Corp Events Workbook></tr><tr/><tr/>" +
            "<tr><th align='left'>Status</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" +
            "<th align='left'>Sedol</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" + 
            "<th align='left'>Name</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" + 
            "<th align='left'>Date Effective</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" + 
            "<th align='left'>Event Code</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" + 
            "<th align='left'>Terms</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# Escape characters using the letter `\` followed by another letter, example: a newline escape: `\n`. Since there is no `\S` escape character in C# (see the list here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) the compiler can't parse it. To solve it us `\\`, the escape sequnce followed by the backslash so the compiler will know you mean to print `\`.

Exmaple:

```
string htmlHeader = "<table style='font-size: 12pt;'>" +
            "<tr><a href='file:///G:\\Shared\\Team\\New\\Corporate%20Actions\\Corp%20Events.xlsx'>Corp Events Workbook></tr><tr/><tr/>" +
            "<tr><th align='left'>Status</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" +
            "<th align='left'>Sedol</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" + 
            "<th align='left'>Name</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" + 
            "<th align='left'>Date Effective</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" + 
            "<th align='left'>Event Code</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" + 
            "<th align='left'>Terms</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>";
```

Notice the second line, on the path part, there is a double left-backslash instead of one.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a `@` in front of your string(part) containing the escape sequence
like:

```
string htmlHeader = "<table style='font-size: 12pt;'>" +
        @"<tr><a href='file:///G:\Shared\Team\New\Corporate%20Actions\Corp%20Events.xlsx'>Corp Events Workbook></tr><tr/><tr/>" +
        "<tr><th align='left'>Status</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" +
        "<th align='left'>Sedol</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" + 
        "<th align='left'>Name</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" + 
        "<th align='left'>Date Effective</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" + 
        "<th align='left'>Event Code</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" + 
        "<th align='left'>Terms</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>";
```

Not *the most clean* solution but its a working solution.I would advise your to look at UnTraDe response aswell.

Comment: I don't think it will work since it's not a single string, he's using the + sign to connect servel strings togheter. It may work if he will put @ infront of everyline, or merge it all to one string like that: `string htmlHeader = @"<table style='font-size:12pt;'<tr><a href='file:///G:\Shared\Team\New\Corporate%20Actions\Corp%20Events.xlsx'>Corp Events Workbook></tr><tr/><tr/><tr><th align='left'>Status</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th align='left'>Sedol</th><th>&nbsp;</th>";`

Comment: Just tested it, it works :) No more errors here with that string.